# Stop body scrolling under overlay

Tags: css, mobile, frontend

I have an overlay menu that displays over the content on mobile. I can't seem to stop the content from scrolling under the menu on iOS or Android. Everywhere I look says to use overflow: hidden; on the body...which I have done and it's not working.

I have the site up on staging here: http://stage.cribbsfuture.truedigital.co.uk/

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Would you show any code you've tried already to prevent the scroll? There are some options, but knowing what you've already implemented would help avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

On touch devices, you have to prevent the `touchmove` event in order to avoid unwanted scroll under overlays.

The following should suit your needs:

```
element.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$(element).on('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```